# Apache Camel JMS with CXF

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I have some services and want that they work with queue. My camelContext:

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="serviceEndpoint" 
   address="/serviceEndpoint"
   serviceName="s:SomeService"
   serviceClass="app.org.SomeService">
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
...
<camel:camelContext>
  <camel:route>
    <camel:from uri = "cfx:bean:serviceEndpoint?dataFormat=MESSAGE/>
    <camel:to uri = "cfxbean:serviceImpl/>
  </camel:route>
</camel:camelContext>
```

Has any ideas?

Comment: Hi, Do you want to use messaging queue?

Comment: I want it uses as postponed queue. If I send message to service, but it is inaccessible

Comment: Hi ,
 As per your latest comment , you say the cxf service is inaccessible.
 Please refer below snippet for camel context. Hope it helps!


 <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="routerEndpoint" address="XXXXXX"
            serviceClass="YYYYYY"/>
    
     <camelContext id="camel">
       <route>
         <from uri="cxf:bean:routerEndpoint" />
         <to uri="cxf:bean:*****" />
       </route>
    </camelContext>

Comment: instead of using cfx:bean use cxf:bean...